# Exporting Illustrator image for CMYK printing using jpg

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-format, file-size

I'm wondering if I need to convert fonts to outline when exporting to a jpg? I assume not, but it's been a while since I've had anything printed. I want to have the best quality but still have it be easy to send online.

I've tried a PDF but it's too large with the photos I'm using in the file.

Comment: Have you tried methods to simply reduce your PDF's file size?

Answer (score 2):

Well JPG is not an optimal format.

PDF would be *much* preferred.

Anyway, when you export a JPG **everything** is rasterized. So, there's no specific direct need to create type outlines prior to exporting.

---

I don't know what online service you are using to print, but customarily PDFs for print are *the size they need to be for quality reasons*. Yes, they are typically larger than a JPG, but there's a valid reason why they are larger. *Most* print services would really prefer a quality PDF to reproduce than a jpg.

Comment: Actually, a JPEG could be exactly the same quality and size as a PDF, depending on the pixels/resolution of the JPEG and depending on what's in the PDF. 

! Everything ! has to be rasterized at some point for output, even PDFs. A PDF can be resolution independent -- but only if it contains vectors and fonts. If a PDF contains only an image, it's really not very different from a JPEG file. In fact, the contents might be essentially a JPEG image.

Comment: JPGs don't contain type hinting, *ever*. In addition, RIPS typically process vector data at MUCH higher PPIs like 2400 or 48000. So a JPG simply *won't* be the same quality as a PDF. That's not to say a JPG will be junk, just not anywhere near as good as a PDF. The two formats, coming from a vector data setup.... can not be equated.